# SignInManager uses fixed claimTypes while UserManager uses configurable ones. Is it correct?

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I am looking a bit under the AspNetCore/Identity/UserManager and SignInManager still wondering if I should use this implementation or should I just copy and adapt to whatever i need.

Looking over the `SignInManager` I noticed something really wierd, and perhaps somebody could help clarify this for me.

The `userManager` class has the ClaimTypes configurable and the default value for the userId is `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`.
The SignInManager does not use the same approach.

1. Is there a reason why they are using `ClaimTypes.Name` in `SignInManager` to check for the `userId`?
2. Is the implementation of the method in the `SignInManager` correct? What happens if I decide to change the type of the claim for the name and userid in the `UserManager` options

Maybe I don't understand but I hope that somebody can explain it to me.

Thanks

[image]